# Tracking history in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to create an application using mongoDB, which can track the history of something, for the purposes of this question lets say the price of books.

I have a collection that has documents currently as such,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595bf365d8dd224be0818690"),
    "isbn" : 1234567890123,
    "title" : "My awesome example book",
    "author": "Author McAutherson",
    "priceNow": 13.75
}
```

now, I'd like to add a history of the prices, so I can access them later, which would have a result similar to

```
{
    "isbn" : 1234567890123,
    "title" : "My awesome example book",
    "author": "Author McAutherson",
    "priceNow": 13.75,
    "priceHistory": [
        {
            "price": 20.43,
            "date": "2017-06-07"
        },
        {
            "price": 10.28,
            "date": "2017-05-03"
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is, should I store the price history in a separate collection and document referencing the `_id` of the original document, or in the original document, and how would I move the current `priceNow` into the `priceHistory` when it changes?

Comment: It really depends on what your actual usage of the data is intended to be. If you "regularly" need to "include" the information along with the parent data then it is probably best to keep it embedded. This also has the advantage of being a "single point of write", since you can both `$set` the current price and `$push` any "history" in the same operation. There is the BSON limit to consider, but 16MB is quite a lot. You can also "modify" the array when adding to only keep a certain number of items if "recent enough" is the actual requirement.

Comment: The one modification of note here is when considering "embedding" this, you should in fact keep "every" item in the "history", including the "current". This is because it is not possible with an "atomic" operation to "reference an existing value" of a document. For example you cannot add a new "current price" and have the "old current" appended to the "history" within an atomic transaction. You can however "set the current" and "also push the current to the history" within the same atomic transaction. But without further clarification on the use case, the  general question is a bit too broad.